# Is the following Grammar suitable for parsing Swift

Tags: swift, parsing, compilation

Apple publishes the grammar of swift here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/zzSummaryOfTheGrammar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH38-ID458

Is the grammar at the link above adequate for generating a parser using ANTLR, YAK,  or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it's fairly complete, however you might want to look at [this project](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift/Swift.g4). It already has done a lot of the work to parse Swift code.

If I might ask, what are you trying to accomplish by parsing Swift code?

Comment: In my unit tests, I end up writing alot of boiler plate code to do a manual mock of my classes.  This is because Swift does not support the level of reflection needed for a traditional mocking framework.  My personal project is to create a script to create these mock classes for me.  Possibly added to the build script of my project./

Comment: [SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) looks very promising for this kind of use. I'd imagine you could use it in a script to get all the structure information you need and build up your mocks. I haven't ever worked with it so it might not do enough for you.

Comment: Ahh...interesting.  Taking a look at the "adorable" project now.  Thanks!